How to identify the relationship between stability and local chemical environment of different facets?
Are there any physical quantities that can characterize the local chemical environment of surfaces with different orientations? I have found that different facets in my system have varying stabilities with respect to water, but I don't know how to characterize this mechanistically.

Are you referring to a long-range electrostatics type of calculation? Particle Mesh Ewald calculations of the system could help describe that. Lennard-Jones PME calculations characterize these long-range interactions over molecular dynamics simulations, but could also be used to generate a static picture of the environment.
